# String passed through intent resolving back to null

Tags: android

Hi i am having a bit of trouble passing a string from an activity to a broadcast reciver.

```
    public class MyBroadcaseciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

MediaPlayer mymedia;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm);
    mymedia.start();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String sample = intent.getExtras().getString("string");
    String mydata = sample;


    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Rain Alert")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("from"))
            .setContentText("Rainfall " + sample + intent.getStringExtra("string"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);


    if (intent != null) {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

}

the above code in my Broadcastreciver

the below is my Alarm acivity from were iam trying to pass the string

```
   public class Alarm extends AppCompatActivity {

MyBroadcaseciver mAppReceiver = new MyBroadcaseciver();


String weather;
Double Lat, Lon;
String key = "45d263e3555d4f0d528ea032cdb1f10e";
private TextView t;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);


    String rainurl = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=53.45523808&lon=-6.18634225&cnt=1&appid=45d263e3555d4f0d528ea032cdb1f10e");

    new GetWeatherTask(t).execute(rainurl);
    int i = 8;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcaseciver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);


}


private class GetWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TextView t;
    double rain = 0.0;
    String units = "imperial";

    String rainurl = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=53.45523808&lon=-6.18634225&cnt=2&appid=45d263e3555d4f0d528ea032cdb1f10e");


    public GetWeatherTask(TextView t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        double rain = 0.0;
        String weather = "UNDEFINED";
        try {

            URL rainurl = new URL(strings[0]);


            HttpURLConnection rainurlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) rainurl.openConnection();


            InputStream rainstream = new BufferedInputStream(rainurlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader rainbufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rainstream));
            StringBuilder rainbuilder = new StringBuilder();


            String raininputString;
            while ((raininputString = rainbufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                rainbuilder.append(raininputString);
            }


            JSONObject raintopLevel = new JSONObject(rainbuilder.toString());
            //JSONObject main = topLevel.getJSONObject("main");

            // weather = String.valueOf(main.getDouble("rain" +
            //         ""));


            JSONArray listArray = raintopLevel.getJSONArray("list");
            JSONObject firstObject = (JSONObject) listArray.get(0);
            rain = firstObject.getDouble("clouds");


            Log.d("Look at this here lad" + rain, "");


            weather = "" + rain;


            // Log.d("SS"+jArray.length(),"");


            rainurlConnection.disconnect();


        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        registerReceiver(mAppReceiver, new IntentFilter("MyReceiver"));


        return weather;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String weather) {


        t.setText(weather);

        String string = "Passed" + weather;
        Intent passintent = new Intent("MyReceiver");
        passintent.putExtra("string", string);
        sendBroadcast(passintent);


    }


}
```

}

this works as expected on the first time a notification fires from my broadcast receiver but the a few seconds later the notification goes again and the value is null i have been trying it for afew hours and have gotten nowhere any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: What do you mean `the notification goes again`?

Comment: I have an alarm manager that calls a notification that is supposed to display the value of the passed string

Comment: Can you post full code? There is nothing I can tell looking at the code you posted. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @GokhanArik Hi i edited my question to have two full code the Alarm is called from my main activity when i press a button

Answer (score 0):

In your broadcast receiver replace `intent.getExtras` to  `intent.getStringExtra`.